# Getting sum of last index in certain arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get the sum of the last indexes of certain arrays.
Some context for the if block for field lengths. I'm splitting the lines at the commas and some lines have more than 4 commas. Here's an example of the 3 lines I'm splitting and getting the sum of:

1, Alabama -- Statewide, Federal Government, 120617581

1, "Dallas County, Alabama", Federal Government, 184304

1, Arkansas -- Statewide, Federal Government, 104630831

```
    // Creates ArrayList for totals
   ArrayList <Double> totals = new ArrayList <Double>();       
             
   // While loop to read each row from file
   while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
       String currentLine = inputFile.nextLine();
       String[] fields = currentLine.split("[,]");
       quarter = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
       region = fields[1];        
        if (fields.length == 4) {    // If block to give indexes to field lengths of 4 and 5
            typeIndex = 2;
            dollarIndex = 3;
        }
        else {
            typeIndex = 3;
            dollarIndex = 4;
        }
        govtType = fields[typeIndex];
        if (fields[1].equals("U.S. TOTAL")) {
            break;
        }
        if (region.contains("Statewide") || govtType.contains("Federal Government") || govtType.contains("State Government")) {    // if block to convert last index into double
        dollar = Double.parseDouble(fields[dollarIndex]);
        }
        if (quarter == 1 && govtType.contains("Federal Government")) {    // If block to get sum of last index of certain arrays
            sum += dollar;
            totals.add(sum);
            System.out.println(totals);
        }
    } // While loop end
```

My output from getting the sum looks like this

[1.20617581E8]

[1.20617581E8, 1.20801885E8]

[1.20617581E8, 1.20801885E8, 2.25432716E8]

I don't know why it's adding into the array every time it goes through the if block. I just want to get the final sum and put it into the array list.

Comment: Why do you want a list to store the sum?

Comment: Why a `double` for inputs of integers?

Answer (score 1):

It's adding into the array because you're initialising it as an array

```
 ArrayList <Double> totals = new ArrayList <Double>();
```

If you want to calculate total sum then just initialise it as a double instead

```
double totals = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying/want to do, to summarize the double numbers and put them in the *List*, or put the interim summaries in the *List*?

I hope that I understand your question correctly. From what I can see your data is:

> 1, Alabama -- Statewide, Federal Government, 120617581
>
> 1, "Dallas County, Alabama", Federal Government, 184304
>
> 1, Arkansas -- Statewide, Federal Government, 104630831

You are using *String[] fields = currentLine.split("[,]");* and it translates into:

- Field[0] is quarter;
- Field[1] is region;
- Field[2] is govType;
- Field[3] is dollar

You've surrounded the value in *field[1]* in the second data-line with *"* so the JVM make is into *"Dallas County, Alabama"*, meaning a string, thus ignoring the comma inside.

Your condition after *region = fields[1];* is always *true* and your condition to add the sum to your *List* is also *true* every time for the given data.

Check your code carefully, recommend you use *System.out.println* to verify you are getting what you expect to get.